# Как создать базу в VS и заполнить ее данными?

Tags: c++, база-данных, visual-studio, oracle, visual-studio-2015

Хочу создать программу на С++ в Visual Studio, которая работала бы с базой данных Oracle. Есть уже созданный DDL скрипт. Как создать базу в VS и заполнить ее данными? (Желательно подробную инструкцию)

Comment: 1. Вам необходимо установить Сервер базы данных Oracle;  
1.1. Выполнить скрипт и создать необходимую Вам бд;
2. Установить коннекторы для бд;
3. Настроить подключение к необходимой бд в проекте

Comment: @Bald Пожалуйста, если владеете темой, преобразуйте свой коментарий в ответ.

Comment: @Cerbo ну мой коммент вряд ли можно считать полноценным ответом, это скорее подсказка. В целом не совсем понятно что *конкретно* не получается у автора. создать БД, подключиться к ней(в смысле к бд), или как получить тестовые данные и записать их в бд

Comment: @Bald Вопрос не о том что "не получается", а о том "как" создать и забить базу. Вопрос весьма полезный к стати.

Answer (score 1):

VisualStudio и Oracle - очень плохо интегрированы на текущий момент. Но если так уж хочется напрямую из VisualStudio работать с Oracle вам понадобится скачать драйвер-плагин поддерживающий версию вашей VS (на офф.сайте Oracle бесплатно).

Но мой вам совет не мучаться таким способом. Работайте с БД Oracle через более дружественные программы такие как PL/SQL Developer и подобоные. А уже потом написанный код в БД вызывайте и используйте в VisualStudio (вам понадобится драйвер Oracle для VS).

Не помню что из этого драйвер, а что плагин для интеграции студии и VS (но думаю сами разберетесь):

- ODTwithODAC (интеграция)
- Oracle Data Tools for VS (драйвер для подключения к БД из проектов VS)

Для подключения в VS к БД надо будет в проекте подключать DLL "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll" которая появится на вашем ПК после установки драйвера в папке куда установите. Добавляете в проекте ссылку на нее и в разделах USING (C#) и там уже гугл в помощь - используется очень легко и понятно. В общих чертах:

- OracleClient
- OracleCommand
- OracleDataAdapter